# Using LightInject, how can I register a generic service with a factory method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I want to configure a logger that logs to xUnit test output, and should be substituted for all `ILogger<T>` dependencies. As far as I can tell, the way to solve this is to use a generic service with a factory method.

<del>When using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, I can do the following:</del>

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(ILogger<>), 
  factory => factory.GetRequiredService<LoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("TestLogger"));
```

<del>How can I achieve the same using LightInject?</del>

**EDIT:** My example does not work, because the created logger cannot be cast to `ILogger<T>`. I have instead posted my workaround as a solution below.

Comment: Have you tried that particular code snippet? It doesn't work. It will throw the following exception when you build the service provider: "Open generic service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TCategoryName]' requires registering an open generic implementation type." What you are trying to do is not possible in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Second point: even if MS.DI would be smart enough to call the factory method whenever you resolve an `ILogger<SomeType>`, the resolve would fail because the logger created from `CreateLogger` can't be cast to `ILogger<SomeType>`. You might want to take a step back and describe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Good feedback, I admit I have not tried executing my code example. I am trying to provide a logger that logs to xUnit test output. I have found a workaround, will post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to solve my problem in a different way:

1. I copied over `XunitLogger` from [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Testing](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Testing/XunitLoggerProvider.cs)
2. I created a generic version:

   ```
   public class XunitLogger<T> : XunitLogger, ILogger<T>
   {
       public XunitLogger(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output, typeof(T).Name, LogLevel.Information)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. I registered the test output helper and the logger:

   ```
   public TestBase(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
   {
       Container.RegisterInstance(testOutputHelper);
       Container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(XunitLogger<>));
   }
   ```

The key here was that `ILogger<T>` must be implemented by a generic class, e.g. `XunitLogger<T>`. Now the messages are logged to my test output.